# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':url_launcher_android:syncReleaseLibJars' (type 'LibraryAarJarsTask')

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, apk

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':url_launcher_android:syncReleaseLibJars' (type 'LibraryAarJarsTask').

> File '/User/build/url_launcher_android/intermediates/annotations_typedef_file/release/typedefs.txt' specified for property 'typedefRecipe' does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I solved this issue by deleting the .gradle file in the android folder in the project file.
- Run flutter clean.
- Restart the app from scratch.